# JS or CSS - Ads page: how to show only adds of certain category?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do an ads page. Each ad is in a format of a card/post-it. I have a top menu with the categories, and i wan't to show only the cards of the categories the user clicks.

here is an example

[codepen - ads page](https://codepen.io/manelfields/pen/rmaPZG)

What to i have to do to enable this?
Do i have to give each category a class name and then put:

```
display: block;
or
display: none;
```

?
Also, can i do it just with CSS, or i have to do it with Javascript?

Please, i'm trying to learn Vanilla Javascript, so i would be very grateful for answers without jquery :)

Comment: Will each category be a separate page, or will all the categories be on a single page (for example as tabs)? Also, are you planning on building a single page application (via AJAX) or a traditional website?

Comment: single page. Not tabs. For example, in the "home", all the ads will be visible. When a certain category is clicked, all the others disappear.

Comment: about AJAX or traditional website...don't know the implications of each :) newbie here

Comment: One way to do this is via tabs (HTML, CSS, JS), a complete example is available here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp (if you use Bootstrap then take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Alternatively, you could indeed use JS to toggle the `display` attribute by attaching an event handler to each category which would hide all the other ads and display only the ads relating to the clicked on category. A third option would be to use AJAX, especially if the ads are likely to change (in a real application they would).

Comment: No worries, if you're planning on building a real application then I'd definitely recommend looking at AJAX first. Vanilla JS example: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp and jQuery method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - jQuery does make it much easier to manage.

Comment: You could also use radio boxes for a pure css solution.

Comment: don't understand how that could do the job. Any more hints @AnuragDaolagajao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure css solution, you can use radio boxes for a horizontal accordion effect. You can search for radio boxes and accordion.

Building on the code you provided, you can try the following

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.category-tab-input {
  display: none;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.category-tab-label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted pink;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

#categories input:checked~.teste {
  display: flex;
}

.teste {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
}

.card {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 245px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 0.85em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: max-height 3s;
}
```

```html
<section id="categories">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="category-tab" id="category-tab-1" class="category-tab-input" checked/>
      <label for="category-tab-1" class="category-tab-label">Immob</label>
      <ul class="teste">
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 1
            <br> Item 1
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 1
            <br> Item 2
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 1
            <br> Item 3
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 1
            <br> Item 4
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="category-tab" id="category-tab-2" class="category-tab-input" />
      <label for="category-tab-2" class="category-tab-label">Rénovation</label>
      <ul class="teste">
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 2
            <br> Item 1
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 2
            <br> Item 2
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="category-tab" id="category-tab-3" class="category-tab-input" />
      <label for="category-tab-3" class="category-tab-label">Équilibre</label>
      <ul class="teste">
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 3
            <br> Item 1
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 3
            <br> Item 2
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="card">
          <p>Tab 3
            <br> Item 3
            <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I was not sure how many items were there for each subcategory, so I added mine unequally to show you the layout. Customise it as per your requirements.